# How can I loop through a directory and add a prefix to filenames where not already present?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I think the title says it all, what I need to do is loop through all images in a directory on my Ubuntu vb, check for a prefix (for example 'ql_') if it already has the prefix, I want to leave it alone, if not I want to add the prefix to the filename.

If you have time to briefly explain what you've done I would be especially grateful as I am desperately trying to get my head into Linux. (e. G what the commands you are using do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern matching operator in `tcsh` makes short work of this.  I've used quotes around the `$i` substitutions in case any filenames contain spaces.

```
foreach i (*)
   if ( "$i" !~ ql_* ) mv "$i" ql_"$i"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Nicole, worked like a charm. I had never heard of tcsh before, seems handy. I'll have to check it out i more depth.

Comment: `tcsh` is Bill Joy's [Berkeley C shell](http://www.kitebird.com/csh-tcsh-book/csh-intro.pdf).  The `t` means it's the version that includes filename completion and command line editing.  I'd start with the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), which is pretty good.  The very best book on it is still the 1986 [UNIX C Shell Field Guide](http://www.amazon.com/The-Unix-Shell-Field-Guide/dp/013937468X/ref=sr_1_1?qid=1355849993) even though it's a little out of date; this was the book that I kept at my side when I wrote [my own C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm).